# How is data from one Behave step passed to a later step?

Tags: python, python-behave

Consider a Behave scenario:

```
When some magic number is generated
Then the number should be greater than 5
```

So I have a @when function that produces (say) a random number and I need that number to be present in the @then conditional test.

How do I pass the result of one step to another?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can set data on the context object passed in to the steps. From [the documentation](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#context):

```
@given('I request a new widget for an account via SOAP')
def step_impl(context):
    client = Client("http://127.0.0.1:8000/soap/")
    context.response = client.Allocate(customer_first='Firstname',
        customer_last='Lastname', colour='red')

@then('I should receive an OK SOAP response')
def step_impl(context):
    eq_(context.response['ok'], 1)
```

You can also [modify the context at various other points](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#environmental-controls) in the test run, before and after every step, feature, scenario, tag, etc.

Comment: Right, but where is the context object defined? In documents it is said that it is an instance of behave.runner.Context but its an undefined object hanging around.

Comment: @Kasra Why is it important where it's defined? Is there a problem?

Comment: At the moment of writing my comment, I was trying to make use of context. And I didn't know that 'behave' is handling it as sort of a universal object. And you're right, no point to talk about where the context is passed from in this topic. Thanks!